# Data column expression with variable

Tags: vb.net, variables, datatable, expression

I have following code and it is not working and calculate cost is zero. What is the mistake here?

```
.Columns.Add("Total", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
.Columns("Total").Expression = "200 * " & FxRate.ToString
```

FxRate is a public variable.

Comment: There does not seem to be any mistake in the code that your are showing. Error must be elesewhere.

Comment: Why are you using an expression that yields a constant value?  Or do you think that when `FxRate` changes, the `Total` fields should automatically update (that will not happen)?

Comment: Yes.  when FxRate changes, the Total fields should automatically update..how do i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when FxRate changes, the Total fields should automatically update.

The `DataColumn.Expression` does not provide a way to reference external variables.  However, you can update the expression at any time.

You will need to call the update method when `FxRate` changes.  If `FxRate` is a property, you can call the update method from its setter method.

Changes to the Expression will not be automatically be reflect on bound control.  The update method will also need to tell the bindings to update.  If you are binding through a `BindingSource` instance, call its `ResetBindings(False)` method.  If you are binding directly to the `DataTable, a more complex method would be to obtain the`DataTable`'s`CurrencyManager`and call its`Refresh` method.

Assuming the `DataTable` variable is named `dt`, the following code will acquire the `CurrencyManager`;  `Me` refers to the containing `Form`.

```
Dim mngr As CurrencyManager = CType(Me.BindingContext.Item(dt), CurrencyManager)
mngr.Refresh()
```

---

**Edit:  A working example using a BindingSource  as requested in the comments.**

In a new WinForm project, replace the contents of Form1.vb with the following code (all controls are created by this code - no designer support).

The code creates: a `TextBox` for changing the "Quantity" field", a `Label` to display the "Total" field, a `NumericUpDown` to allow changing the value of the `FxRate` property, and two button to allow navigating through the records in the `DataTable`.

The `DataTable` has three records.  A record comprise two fields "Quantity" and "Total".  "Total" will be computed as the product of the form's FxRate property and and the field "Quantity" by setting the `Expression` property of the "Quantity" column each time `FxRate` changes.

```
Public Class Form1
  Inherits Form

  Private tbInput As TextBox
  Private lblTotal As Label
  Private nudFxRate As NumericUpDown
  Private btnNext As Button
  Private btnPrevious As Button

  Private bs As BindingSource
  Private _FxRate As Int32
  Private dt As DataTable

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    SetupControls()
    dt = New DemoTable ' create a preconfigured DataTable
    bs = New BindingSource(dt, Nothing)
    SetBindings()
    FxRate = 5
    AttachControlEventHandlers()
  End Sub

  Public Property FxRate As Int32
    Get
      Return _FxRate
    End Get
    Set(value As Int32)
      If value <> _FxRate Then
        _FxRate = value
        UpdateTotalExpression() ' only update the Expression if the value changes
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

  Private Sub UpdateTotalExpression()
    ' Change the expression to reflect the current value of FxRate
    Dim totalColumn As DataColumn = dt.Columns("Total")
    totalColumn.Expression = $"[Quantity] * {FxRate}"
    ' Expression changes do not notify the BindingSource of value changes
    ' so tell the BindingSource to reload all values
    bs.ResetBindings(False)
  End Sub

  Private Sub tbInput_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) Then
      Me.Validate()     ' force tbInput to Validate
      e.Handled = True  ' eat the enter key
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub tbInput_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' if tbInput successfully validated, push the values in the BindingSource to the DataTable
    bs.EndEdit() ' push the editted value to the DataTable, causing Total to update
  End Sub

  Private Sub SetBindings()
    ' Update BindingSource once tbInput Validates successfully
    tbInput.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Quantity", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation)
    ' lblTotal never updates the BindingSource
    lblTotal.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Total", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never)
    ' nudFxRate updates the FxRate property
    nudFxRate.DataBindings.Add("Value", Me, "FxRate", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
  End Sub

  Private Sub SetupControls()
    tbInput = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    lblTotal = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    nudFxRate = New System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown()
    btnNext = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    btnPrevious = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    CType(nudFxRate, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    SuspendLayout()
    '
    'tbInput
    '
    tbInput.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(27, 40)
    tbInput.Name = "tbInput"
    tbInput.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 22)
    tbInput.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'lblTotal
    '
    lblTotal.AutoSize = False
    lblTotal.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    lblTotal.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(299, 42)
    lblTotal.Name = "lblTotal"
    lblTotal.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 17)
    lblTotal.TabIndex = 1
    lblTotal.Text = "0"
    '
    'nudFxRate
    '
    nudFxRate.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(28, 94)
    nudFxRate.Name = "nudFxRate"
    nudFxRate.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(120, 22)
    nudFxRate.TabIndex = 3
    nudFxRate.Value = 5
    '
    'btnNext
    '
    btnNext.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(27, 136)
    btnNext.Name = "btnNext"
    btnNext.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    btnNext.TabIndex = 4
    btnNext.Text = "Next"
    btnNext.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btnPrevious
    '
    btnPrevious.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(28, 171)
    btnPrevious.Name = "btnPrevious"
    btnPrevious.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    btnPrevious.TabIndex = 5
    btnPrevious.Text = "Previous"
    btnPrevious.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Form1
    '
    AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(8.0!, 16.0!)
    AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
    Controls.Add(btnPrevious)
    Controls.Add(btnNext)
    Controls.Add(nudFxRate)
    Controls.Add(lblTotal)
    Controls.Add(tbInput)
    Name = "Form1"
    Text = "Form1"
    CType(nudFxRate, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    ResumeLayout(False)
    PerformLayout()

  End Sub

  Private Sub AttachControlEventHandlers()
    AddHandler btnNext.Click, Sub() bs.MoveNext()  ' move to next record in bindingsource
    AddHandler btnPrevious.Click, Sub() bs.MovePrevious() ' move to previous record in bindingsource
    AddHandler tbInput.KeyPress, AddressOf tbInput_KeyPress ' allow enter key to validate textbox
    AddHandler tbInput.Validated, AddressOf tbInput_Validated ' update bindingsource on validation
  End Sub

  Private Class DemoTable : Inherits DataTable
    Public Sub New()
      Columns.Add("Quantity", GetType(Int32))
      Columns.Add("Total", GetType(Int32))
      Rows.Add(New Object() {10})
      Rows.Add(New Object() {20})
      Rows.Add(New Object() {30})
    End Sub
  End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for both the inputs . If i add new column FxRate like RobertBaron said ..it calculates ..but i will have lot of variables to multiply.  Adding a column for each variable is not my preference. FxRate is taken as zero when new row is added i dont know why. I have datatable bound to bindingsource and all my controls are databound to this bindingsource. TnTinMn i tried you currency manager method combined with the FxRate column but the values are not updating when i change the FxRate. Could provide one simple example? Thanks.

Comment: @shan, I don't understand why you used the CurrencyManager when I stated to use `BindingSource.ResetBindings(False)` method if you are using a binding source. In any case, I added an example using a BindingSource.  Also, there is no advantage in adding a column for `FxRate` just to use the Expression as you would need to set the value on each row.  In that case, you might as well just compute the Total value and set it for each row.  You also still need to detect when `FxRate` changes to perform that operation.

Comment: Thank you very much TnTinMn..thats a lot of effort to answer my question. I will take a look and try to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Add the column FxRate. Change the expression of the Total column to `"200 * FxRate"`, and the value of the Total column will be automatically set based on whatever `FxRate` is set to.

```
.Columns.Add("FxRate", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))

.Columns.Add("Total", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
.Columns("Total").Expression = "200 * FxRate"

' Example of setting FxRate in row 0.
' (Assuming row 0 exists.)
.Rows(0).Item("FxRate") = 3
```

Comment: .Columns("FxRate").Value = FxRate  ...it gives me error. should be .defaultvalue? .